# Deferred evaluation of bash variables

Tags: bash

I need to define a string (`options`) which contains a variable (`group`) that is  going to be available later in the script.

This is what I came up with, using a literal string that gets evaluated later.

```
#!/bin/bash

options='--group="$group"' #$group is not available at this point

#
# Some code...
#

group='trekkie'
eval echo "$options" # the result is used elsewhere
```

It works, however it makes use of `eval` which I would like to avoid if not absolutely necessary (I don't want to risk potential problems because of unpredictable data).

I've asked for help in multiple places and I've got a couple of answers that were directing me to use [indirect variables](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/006).

The problem is I simply fail to see how indirect variables might help me with my problem. As far as I understand they only offer a way of indirectly referencing other variables like this:

```
options="--group="$group""
a=options
group='trekkies'
echo "${!a}" # spits out --group=
```

I would also like to avoid using functions if possible because I don't want to make things more complicated than they need to be.

Comment: Using `eval` is **much** more complicated than using functions (in terms of the room for side effects). In what respect do you see using a function as making things difficult?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy The script is already 150+ lines long and I have a rule that says anything above 100 lines in bash is a good candidate for an alternative tool (Python etc.) With functions I would also need to complicate things with passing arguments which seems like awfully lot complication for simply evaluating a variable inside a string.

Comment: If you don't know bash well enough to use functions without adding length, you *should* rewrite this in Python. Doubly so if you would otherwise use `eval`.

Comment: ...by the way, I'm sure you've already seen it linked if you've searched around in this problem space, but [BashFAQ #50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) is somewhat mandatory reading.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy It would be a shame to scrap all the work I've already done because the script actually works. I am just trying to add an additional feature which would dynamically adjust some options. I also did read the page you linked, several times but I don't think I made any huge offence in my script regarding separation of commands and data.

Comment: What is a typical value of `$group`? What if you get an *atypical* value?

Comment: @chepner The code I've given here only functionally resembles what I am really working on. `$group` has no real connection to my script. However, for the sake of completeness `$group` is supposed to always contain only alphanumeric values and it's highly unlikely it will ever contain anything else. I'd still like to cover all the grounds, hence my attempt to avoid eval.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### More Idiomatic: Using Parameter Expansion

Don't attempt to define the `--group="$group"` argument up-front when you don't yet know the group name; instead, set a flag that indicates whether the argument is needed, and honor that flag when forming your final argument list.

By going the below approach, you avoid any need for "deferred evaluation":

```
#!/bin/bash

# initialize your flag as unset
unset needs_group

# depending on your application logic, optionally set that flag
if [[ $application_logic_here ]]; then
  needs_group=1
fi

# ...so, the actual group can be defined later, when it's known...
group=trekkies

# and then check the flag to determine whether to pass the argument:
yourcommand ${needs_group+--group="$group"}
```

If you don't need the flag to be separate from the group variable, this is even easier:

```
# pass --group="$group" only if "$group" is a defined shell variable
yourcommand ${group+--group="$group"}
```

The relevant syntax is a [parameter expansion](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe): `${var+value}` expands to `value` only if `var` is defined; and unlike most parameter expansions, its value can parse to multiple words with quoting applied.

---

#### Alternately: One-Liner Function Shims

Here, you really *are* defining `--group="$group"` before the `group` is known:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [[ $application_logic_here ]]; then
  with_optional_group() { "$@" --group="$group"; }
else
  with_optional_group() { "$@"; }
fi

group=trekkies

with_optional_group yourcommand
```

Comment: I already thought about this, even did an extensive research if bash supported something like ternary operators (not much luck there). I'll either do something like this or simply rewrite the whole thing with Python.

Comment: See also an added sample showing use of function shims -- the length overhead is notably minimal.

Comment: What exactly is `"$@"`? I know it's a special parameter but never quite understood what it does.

Comment: It expands to the current scope's argument list, each argument as a separate word. It's thus much less inherently error-prone than `$*`, which jumbles everything together into a string (and then, when used unquoted, splits that string back into words).

Comment: I think I have enough new material to refactor my code. Thank you for all your suggestions. I'll leave the question unanswered for now just because of people that might add something to the topic.